# I noticed that the "scope" has disappeared under Github. Any ideas on finding it?

Tags: github

[image]

I tried regenerating different tokens, but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub currently offers two types of Personal Access tokens: Classic tokens, and new in October 2022, [Fine-Grained tokens](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/). Scopes is available under the "Classic" tokens:

[image]